# Why does Html.BeginForm generate empty action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.beginform

I have a controller in an area called `Admin`

```
public class SiteVisitController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult ReadyForCompletion() { ... }

    public ViewResult CompleteAndExport() { ... }
}
```

and a view (`ReadyForCompletion.cshtml`) that has posts back to a different controller action on the same class

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( "CompleteAndExport", "SiteVisit" ))
{        
    <input type="submit" value="Complete &amp; Export" />
}
```

The generated HTML for this form has a blank action:

```
<form action="" method="post">  <input type="submit" value="Complete &amp; Export" />

</form>
```

I want to know **why this has a blank action?** For more info, I also added in a

```
@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "ReadyForCompletion", action = "SiteVisit", area = "Admin" })
```

which also printed out an empty string. Also, if I use an empty `Html.BeginForm()` it generates the correct action.

Registered routes are

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_manyParams",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{actionId}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, actionId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Can you show the registered routes?

Comment: I added the registered routes, but I'm confused by why that would matter since I can successfully do `Html.BeginForm()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe your problem is caused by having consecutive optional parameters. I was not able to replicate your problem until I changed the route to contain two optional parameters.

See: [This article which explains the problem](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you encountering this issue using ASP.NET Core the root cause is the same, though the solution is slightly different. I first saw this in Core using multiple default values when calling `.MapRoutes()`. E.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Bar" }
);
```

The workaround is to place the default values into the string template:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Foo}/{action=Bar}/{id?}"
);
```

YMMV.